# Boolean function represented as a column vector: easy way to see if it has full degree?

Tags: boolean-complexity

If you have a Boolean function $f: \{0,1\}^n \rightarrow \{0,1\}$ on $n$ variables, you can represent this function as a $2^n$ vector indexed by the input space such that $
f_x = f(x)$. For concreteness I assume that $f$ is ordered as 00, 01, 10, 11, etc.

Is there an easy way to tell if $f$ is has full degree? For most examples I checked it seemed that if the vector $f$ is symmetric across its midpoint then the function cannot be full degree.

Comment: What do you mean by "full degree"?

Comment: That the degree of $f$ as a multilinear polynomial in $x_1,\dots,x_n$ is $n$.

Comment: A function has full degree iff it correlate with parity. This gives you a linear time algorithm.

Answer (score 2):

Every function $f\colon \{0,1\}^n \to \{0,1\}$, whose input we style $x_1,\ldots,x_n$, has a unique expansion as a multilinear polynomial in the variables $y_i = (-1)^{x_i} = 1-2x_i$. It also has a unique expansion as a multilinear as a multilinear polynomial in the variables $x_i = (1-y_i)/2$. Both expansions have the same degree: given one of the expansions, substituting the expressions above (either $y_i = 1-2x_i$ or $x_i = (1-y_i)/2$) gives an expansion in terms of the other variables with the same degree.

A function $f\colon \{0,1\}^n \to \{0,1\}$ has full Fourier degree (that is, its expansion in the variables $y_i$ has degree $n$) iff it has non-empty correlation with the parity character $$ \chi_{[n]} = y_1 \cdots y_n = (-1)^{x_1 + \cdots + x_n}. $$
This is because the coefficient of $y_1 \cdots y_n$ in the unique multilinear expansion is exactly this correlation (suitably normalized).

Therefore, all you have to check is whether
$$
\sum_{x \in \{0,1\}^n} f(x) (-1)^{x_1 + \cdots + x_n} \neq 0.
$$

Comment: Thanks for this answer. Can I ask you a follow up question: if $c(f, g)$ denotes the correlation of two multilinear polynomials, then does $c$ have any transitive properties? My guess would be that it doesn't... In either case could you recommend some good references on correlation?

Comment: I’m not sure what you mean by “transitive”. Is real multiplication transitive?

Comment: Oh I'm sorry, what I meant was something like this $c(f, \chi) \neq 0$ and $c(g, f) \neq 0$ implies $c(g, \chi) \neq 0$.

Comment: That’s definitely false. A random function will have nonzero correlation with all Fourier characters, but the latter are all orthogonal.